# Angular - how to ignore a javascript file

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a javascript file that I do not want to bundle with the Angular application, but it has to be stored in a subfolder of the project.

Because this javascript is executed server side, it uses a syntax that is not accepted by webpack.

When I try to execute ng serve, webpack throws an error.

Is there a way to exclude this file?

Comment: Are you using a custom webpack or the default angular one?

Comment: Why do you keep a server-side source file in the client-side directory?

Comment: Can't you store the folder outside of the client folder where ng serve dosn't access ?

Comment: You could always add it to the assets folder

Comment: Your project folder should contain two folders. one for the server use other for client side. Your actual project should go in the latter, and js file in the first

Comment: Webpack shouldn't care if there are files with wrong syntax, if you don't use them. Are you loading the file somewhere?

Comment: @lukas-reineke it does care when I run the build for prod.

Comment: @zmbq It is the opposite: I am keeping the client-side code in a server side folder because the server side will be used to serve the client code.

Comment: Webpack will only try to load them if you have defined them as an entry or require / import them somewhere. Can you share your webpack.config.js?

Comment: @lukas-reineke I do not have any webpack.config.js. It is angular that is configuring webpack.

Comment: The server will serve the generated and bundled js files, it won't serve the actual sources. And it most certainly won't serve its own sources. Separate the server and client code.